# Grunt custom task that alternates between running shell commands and processing JavaScript

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-shell

I've found this question [Grunt Shell output to other task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167750/grunt-shell-output-to-other-task), but what I want to do is a bit more complex.

I'd like to have a custom task that uses grunt-shell commands in a loop.  In each loop iteration I then need to also run grunt functions to manipulate files.  The pseudo-code would be something like

```
accept starting and ending git SHAs

loop over them:
check out the next revision (grunt-shell command)
loop over the files from the grunt task's src config (this.filesSrc) and count instances of a particular string (regex), adding the count for each file to a running total

after we've gathered the data from all commits from start to finish, output the results as JSON (grunt.log or write to a file)
```

I have been able to do the file processing with a custom grunt task, and issuing shell commands with grunt-shell is easy enough to do as a one-time independent task purely via config.  What I'd like to do is know how to issue commands once in a while in the middle of a grunt custom task.  This git repo forensics is the current example, but I'm sure there are other use cases.

Comment: man, just use `make`.

Comment: @Mathletics part of what I'm doing is trying to learn the ropes on grunt.  I could use any number of other tools to accomplish the same thing, but I'd like to see if it's possible with grunt.

Comment: ok, but i think you are using the wrong tool. good luck!

Comment: @Mathletics thanks - yeah, I may be using a hammer to try to paint or do the wiring with :)